# Why does Drop take &mut self instead of self?

Tags: rust

Why does [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Drop.html)’s method have signature `fn drop(&mut self)` instead of `fn drop(self)`? This makes it difficult to move values out of the fields e.g. [`self.join_handle.join()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.join) or `std::mem::drop(self.file)` (error: cannot move out of type `X`, which defines the `Drop` trait).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's look at how `std::mem::drop` is implemented:

```
pub fn drop<T>(_x: T) { }
```

That's right: it's an empty function! That's because it takes advantage of move semantics to acquire ownership of its argument. If `T` implements `Drop`, the compiler automatically inserts a call to `Drop::drop(_x)` at the end of the function. This happens to all arguments received by value (that is, in fact, *all* arguments whatsoever, but dropping a reference doesn't drop the referent).

Now consider what would happen if `Drop::drop` took its argument by value: the compiler would try to invoke `Drop::drop` on the argument within `Drop::drop` — this would cause a stack overflow! And of course, you would be able to call `mem::drop` on the argument, which would also try to recursively call `Drop::drop`.

Comment: Sure, but the compiler could easily special case this case.

Comment: This answer begs the question. The only reason `std::mem::drop` exists at all is so that the caller is forced to give up ownership before `drop` is called. If `drop` accepted `self` directly there would be no need for `std::mem::drop`.

Comment: @GManNickG: there is *absolutely nothing* special about `std::mem::drop`. The only reason it exists at all is for *convenience*, because occasionally you need to drop something (e.g. a lock guard), and `drop(guard);` is prettier than `let _x = guard;`. That `std::ops::Drop::drop` and `std::mem::drop` have the same name is essentially coincidence.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it is unnecessary for `Drop::drop` to take ownership of the value.

In Rust, ownership is automatically handled at language level, and therefore the compiler makes sure to properly implement ownership semantics; thus when a `Foo { a: int, b: String }` goes out of scope, the compiler will drop `Foo` by dropping its inner fields automatically.

It is thus unnecessary for `Drop::drop` to drop the fields!

Actually, *after* `Drop::drop` is called on `Foo`, the compiler will itself `mem::drop` the different fields (which may also invoke `Drop::drop` on those fields which define it, such as `b: String` here).

---

What does `Drop::drop` do, then?

It is used to implement *extra* logic on top of what the compiler will do; taking your `JoinHandle` example:

```
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
#[unsafe_destructor]
impl<T> Drop for JoinHandle<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if !self.0.joined {
            unsafe { imp::detach(self.0.native) }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `Drop::drop` is used to detach the thread, for example.

In a collection such as `Vec::vec`:

```
#[unsafe_destructor]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<T> Drop for Vec<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // This is (and should always remain) a no-op if the fields are
        // zeroed (when moving out, because of #[unsafe_no_drop_flag]).
        if self.cap != 0 && self.cap != mem::POST_DROP_USIZE {
            unsafe {
                for x in &*self {
                    ptr::read(x);
                }
                dealloc(*self.ptr, self.cap)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, as the raw memory is manipulated in a way opaque to the compiler, this implementation takes care of:

1. Dropping each element held by the vector
2. Deallocating the memory

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t clear. I do not intend to manually delete each field. My intention is to call functions that consume some of my fields so that I can wait on a thread or log any errors (I admit that I shouldn’t have brought up `std::mem::drop` which doesn’t tell you any errors that happened).

Comment: @yonran: Well, asking for a rationale as you did is a valid question so I am reluctant to tell you to edit it and completely change it, instead I would advise you to simply ask another question on how to do what you want to do, preferably with a MCVE on [the playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/) that we can tinker with to make sure our solution does compile.

Comment: @yonran: Did you ever ask another question? I'm having exactly the same problem as you; specifically with using [`WavWriter::finalize()`](https://docs.rs/hound/3.0.0/hound/struct.WavWriter.html#method.finalize) in a `Drop()`.

Comment: @Timmmm, sorry, no I didn’t. I think I just used an `Option<T>` in order to consume it during `drop`.