# Why does `Drop::drop` take `&mut self` instead of `self`?

Tags: rust, destructor

I am aware of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30905826/6187172) that was once asked, but I am still rather perplexed after reading the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905994/6187172) (to be clear, I do not see why the compiler does not have a special case for `Drop::drop`, as mentioned in the comments, since it already disallows moving out of an object that implements `Drop`). So let me please try to reiterate on this.

Suppose we have a `struct` `Foo` that owns some resources; say, a thread that has to be joined when the object goes out of scope (this situation can happen if we are writing an asynchronous runtime):

```rust
struct Foo {
    t: JoinHandle<()>,
}
```

Since `std::ops::Drop::drop` takes `&mut self`, with this definition we cannot really hope to join this thread in `drop`, because `JoinHandle::join` takes `self` by value. Therefore, we have to resort to making this field optional:

```rust
struct Foo {
    t: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
}
```

And then we can go with `if let Some(t) = self.t.take() { t.join(); }`. But there still seem to be some unanswered questions here:

1. Is the `drop` signature hinting us that the `drop` method may get called several times on some objects, or that `drop` may not be the last method that is called on an object during its lifetime? If yes, in which scenarios can this happen? Is it correct to write `self.t.unwrap()` in the example above?
2. How to achieve similar semantics without introducing the overhead of `Option` (which may not in all cases get covered by [niche optimisation](https://google.github.io/comprehensive-rust/std/box-niche.html) and is anyway rather verbose)?

Comment: If it were `drop(self)` would you allow that function to call another member functions? What would happen if `drop(self)` would call `foo(self)`? And if it called `bar(&mut self)` after joining your thread?

Comment: I still don't understand what this question is asking, that is different from the linked question.

Comment: Subquestion 1: no, this is explained in the linked question (it's to prevent stack-overflows).

Comment: Subquestion 2: The compiler doesn't force you to use `Option` anywhere. I don't follow the question.

Comment: Well, I suppose we would not want to call the destructor in `foo`. This might not be easy to implement, surely, if we consider calling the destructor a part of `foo`'s code

Comment: @PeterHall, you are right about the subquestion 2, tried to fix

Comment: Your second question can be addressed here: [How can I move a value out of the argument to Drop::drop()?](/q/53254645/2189130) Your best options are `Option` (safe but has overhead) or `ManuallyDrop` (unsafe but has no overhead).